# How to install the same version of Ruby (say 3.1.2) twice in the same machine with rbenv? I'll call one 3.1.2 and one 3.1.2-test

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I want to first test on `3.1.2-test` and then proceed to the `3.1.2`. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Why do you need it? Why don't use docker for this purpose?

Comment: I want to do a bunch of tests with `3.1.2-test` before moving to `3.1.2`. Some people have also said that sometime you want different versions of the same gem installed: one on `3.1.2` and a different one on `3.1.2-test`.

Comment: Found the solution. For those who are interested => https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1171

Comment: What do you want to test with `3.1.2-test` that you cannot test with `3.1.2` when it is the same version?